# Is wxNet still a good solution for mono GUI?

Tags: user-interface, mono, cross-platform, gui-toolkit

I'm looking for opinions from Mono developers.
I want to create applications for Linux/Mac/Windows and looking for the best GUI toolkit option. I'm not asking what the best actually is, because that is a matter of opinions.

My main question is if wxNet is a good option for cross platform GUI's. The main reason I ask this question, is because the 'latest' news on their website is almost 3 years ago. That's a long time in software development.

Is wxNet still a good solution, or should I go for Winforms on Windows, GTK on Linux and MonoMac for OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some years ago it seemed like a decent solution to target all platforms in a native way.

But given that wxWindows is implemented in unmanaged code, and it requires a .NET binding (wxNet), it might be a bit obscure for you to surf the code and fix a bug if you ever find one.

That's why nowadays I recommend [XWT](https://github.com/mono/xwt), which is fully implemented in managed code (C#) and achieves the same native-way in all platforms. (And it is heavily maintained.)